# How do you forcefully refresh Eureka client cache?

Tags: java, netflix-eureka, netflix

I have the requirement of refreshing the Eureka client cache forcefully. The reason for this is that,
Assuming I have a service registered to Eureka with name "A" and the "A"s information is outdated, I do not want to stay until Eureka automatically refreshes its cache.

How do I refresh the Eureka client cache forcefully?

Comment: doesn't eureka have /refresh endpoint?

Comment: @VeselinDavidov This means we have to do an HTTP call manually to the above endpoint? Isn't there any method to handle this automatically? (ex: `DiscoveryManager.getInstance().getDiscoveryClient().refreshRegistry()`) or maybe I am missing a point here? :)

Comment: well I guess there probably is but what will trigger that code? You need to know when that happens. And it's usually the service that knows when it has changed its information. So my idea was for example when "A" has its properties changed to call Eureka's refresh (or to de-register and register itself)

Comment: Thanks @VeselinDavidov ... Eureka client doesn't have a way of invalidating the cache. It happens when polling happens only :)