# Is there any way for API Gateway to find the User service immediately?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

I'm having a problem with Eureka.
I have 3 components:

- Eureka (port 8761)
- User service (port 3001)
- API Gateway (port 2001)

```java
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                // User service
                .route(r -> r.path("/user-service/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/user-service/", "/").dedupeResponseHeader(HttpHeader.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, HttpHeader.RETAIN_UNIQUE))
                        .uri("lb://USER-SERVICE"))

                .build();
    }
```

I start Eureka and API Gateway first, then start User service. I access the user service through API Gateway (http://localhost:2001/user-service) but error "Unable to find instance for USER-SERVICE" is display, and a few seconds later, it works.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDCtH.jpg)

Is there any way for API Gateway to find the User service immediately?

Comment: What is the real problem that you are experiencing? Are you seeing user requests fail initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the property indicating how often(in seconds) to fetch the registry information from the eureka server. The default value is 30s as can be found on [the link](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_appendix_compendium_of_configuration_properties).

```
eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds=30s
```

Comment: I thought this setting is to pick up subsequent changes quickly, does it also help at startup?

Comment: Yes it helps at startup also, because user service is not available at the time the gateway is started, so it waits for new eureka fetch to see if something has changed. Gateway can also be started after user service is registered to eureka, and gateway would found it instantly.

Comment: @birca123 it work! thank you. is there anyway to registry fetch manually?

Comment: I don't think so, as the last comment on [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129726/how-do-you-forcefully-refresh-eureka-client-cache) related to that topic says.