# How do I get the Spring Api Gateway to check Service Registry more often?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

My services work through the **Spring Api Gateway**, if some service is turned off and then turned on, the Gateway "**loses**" it.

( Release2021.0.x aka Jubilee / Spring boot 2.6.x, 2.7.x (Starting with 2021.0.3)

How can **'Spring Api Gateway'** be forced to frequently look into the Eureka Server registry, or can clients be forced to register with **Spring Api Gateway** or somehow inform it?

Otherwise, you have to restart the **'Spring Api Gateway'**.

Comment: How are you defining routes in the gateway?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to reduce the registry fetch interval property as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74093328/10231374) for a similar question.

```
eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds=30s
```